How to find the permutation of a set with limited but allowed repetition?
My question is this:
Suppose I have a set of 10 unique elements. I will draw 8 elements from the set each time. In each draw, I can draw the same element more than once, but not more than 4 times (require at least 5 unique elements). I want to find the total number of permutations (order matters) of the draws.
My initial thought is that I can calculate the permutation with repetition of ${10\choose 8}$ first using $n^r$, then subtract the number of permutations of separate cases where there's only 4, 3, 2, or 1 unique elements. However this approach is obviously not the best way, besides I cannot calculate those cases either. So is there a better way? Thanks in advance!

Can downvoter please explain what can be improved? Thanks!

Here is a systematic way you can attempt it, using the format
$\text{[Lay Down Pattern] x [Permute Pattern]}$
$4111100000: \dfrac{8!}{4!1!1!1!1!}\dfrac{10!}{1!4!5!}= 2116800$
which of course, can be abbreviated to $\dfrac{8!}{4!}\dfrac{10!}{4!5!}$ by omitting $1!s$
Compute similarly for remaining patterns in descending order
$3211100000,\, 3111110000,\, 2221100000,$
$2211110000,\, 2111111000,\,1111111100$
and add up

The exponential generating function for the number of ways to order $n$ elements from a set of size $10$ with each element appearing no more than $4$ times is
$$f(x) = \left( 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 + \frac{1}{3!} x^3 + \frac{1}{4!} x^4 \right)^{10}$$
Expanding $f(x)$ would be tedious by hand but is easy using a computer algebra system.  It turns out that the coefficient of $x^8$ when $f(x)$ is expanded is
$$[x^8]f(x) = \frac{158045}{64}$$
so the number of ways to order $8$ elements with the stated restriction is
$$8! \, [x^8]f(x) = 99,568,350 $$


Suppose I have a set of 10 unique elements. I will draw 8 elements from the set each time. In each draw, I can draw the same element more than once, but not more than 4 times (require at least 5 unique elements). I want to find the total number of permutations (order matters) of the draws.

The first thing to do is identify the number of mutually exclusive ways of partitioning the number $~8~$ into at least $~5~$ non-zero terms.
These are

$P_1 ~: ~$ 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1

$P_2 ~: ~$ 2 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1

$P_3 ~: ~$ 3 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1

$P_4 ~: ~$ 2 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1

$P_5 ~: ~$ 4 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1

$P_6 ~: ~$ 3 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 1

$P_7 ~: ~$ 2 - 2 - 2 - 1 - 1


For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\},~$ 
let $~N_k~$ denote the enumeration that pertains to partition $~P_k.~$
Then, the final computation will be
$$\sum_{k=1}^{7} N_k. \tag0 $$

$\underline{\text{Preliminary Consideration}}$
Given $~x_1, \cdots, x_r \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that $~x_1 + \cdots + x_r = n,~$
I will use the syntax
$$\binom{n}{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_r}$$
to represent
$$\frac{n!}{(x_1!) \times (x_2!) \times \cdots \times (x_r!)}.$$
Suppose that you have the $~r~$ distinct elements $~E_1, ~E_2, ~\cdots, E_r,~$ with these elements being repeated $~x_1, ~x_2, ~\cdots, ~x_r~$ times, respectively.
Then, the number of distinct ways of positioning these elements into $~n~$ places, where order matters is
$$\binom{n}{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_r}.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_1}$
1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{8}~$ ways of choosing the elements, and then $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}~$ ways of permuting them.  So
$$N_1 = \binom{10}{8} \times \binom{8}{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}. \tag1 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_2}$
2 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{9}{6}~$ ways of selecting which element will be repeated twice, and then which $~6~$ other elements will be selected.
Then there are then $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}~$ ways of permuting them.  So
$$N_2 = \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{9}{6} \times \binom{8}{2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}. \tag2 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_3}$
3 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{9}{5}~$ ways of selecting which element will be repeated 3 times, and then which $~5~$ other elements will be selected.
Then there are $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}~$ ways of permuting them.  So
$$N_3 = \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{9}{5} \times \binom{8}{3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}. \tag3 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_4}$
2 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{2} \times \binom{8}{4}~$ ways of selecting which two elements will serve as doubletons and then which other elements will be singletons.
Then there are $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}~$ ways of permuting them.  So
$$N_4 = \binom{10}{2} \times \binom{8}{4} \times \binom{8}{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}. \tag4 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_5}$
4 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{9}{4} ~$ ways of selecting which element will be repeated $~4~$ times and then which other elements will be singletons.
Then there are $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{4, 1, 1, 1, 1}~$ ways of permuting them.  So
$$N_5 = \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{9}{4} \times \binom{8}{4, 1, 1, 1, 1}. \tag5 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_6}$
3 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 1
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{9}{1} \times \binom{8}{3} ~$ ways of selecting the triplet, the doubleton, and then the singletons.
Then there are $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{3, 2, 1, 1, 1}~$ ways of permuting them.  So
$$N_6 = \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{9}{1} \times \binom{8}{3} \times \binom{8}{3, 2, 1, 1, 1}. \tag6 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_7}$
2 - 2 - 2 - 1 - 1
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{7}{2} ~$ ways of selecting the doubletons, and then the singletons.
Then there are $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{2, 2, 2, 1, 1}~$ ways of permuting them.  So
$$N_7 = \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{7}{2} \times \binom{8}{2, 2, 2, 1, 1}. \tag7 $$

$\underline{\text{Final Summary}}$
Use the equations in (1), (2), ..., (7) above to compute each of $~N_1, ~N_2, ~\cdots, ~N_7.$
Then, perform the computation
$$\sum_{k=1}^{7} N_k. $$
